# PlayFramework(2.6.12): Use JKS file in conf folder(relative path) in HTTPS mode

Tags: scala, playframework

My **application.conf**:

```
play.server.https.keyStore {
  path = "conf/cacert.jks"
  type = "JKS"
  password = "n0t_@_$ecret!"
}
```

In `conf` folder I have `cacert.jks`

[DefaultSSLEngineProvider](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.x/framework/src/play-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/ssl/DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala) can't read file with relative path, the condition on this [line is not met](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.x/framework/src/play-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/ssl/DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala#L40):

```
2018-05-14 10:44:23,502 ERROR play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer - Cannot load SSL context
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createScalaSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:103)
    at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:35)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$7.apply(AkkaHttpServer.scala:126)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$7.apply(AkkaHttpServer.scala:124)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.<init>(AkkaHttpServer.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServerProvider.createServer(AkkaHttpServer.scala:464)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServerProvider.createServer(AkkaHttpServer.scala:462)
    at play.core.server.ServerProvider$class.createServer(ServerProvider.scala:25)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServerProvider.createServer(AkkaHttpServer.scala:462)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:57)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:25)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to find HTTPS keystore at "/api/target/universal/stage/conf/cacert.jks"
    at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.createSSLContext(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:56)
    at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.<init>(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:24)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions is to implement [custom SSLEngineProvider](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfiguringHttps#in-Scala,-an-implementation-must-be-provided-for-play.server.api.SSLEngineProvider):

```
package utils

import java.io.File

import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigValueFactory}
import javax.net.ssl._
import play.api.Configuration
import play.core.ApplicationProvider
import play.core.server.ServerConfig
import play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider
import play.server.api._

class CustomSSLEngineProvider(svrCfg: ServerConfig, appProv: ApplicationProvider)
  extends SSLEngineProvider {

  val KEYSTORE_PATH: String = "play.server.https.keyStore.path"
  val config = svrCfg.configuration.underlying
  val keyStoreFile: File = appProv.current.get.environment.getFile(
    config.getString(KEYSTORE_PATH))
  // We override relative path with absolute path - it is needed for DefaultSSLEngineProvider!
  val configWithFixedKeystorePath: Config = config.withValue(KEYSTORE_PATH,
    ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef(keyStoreFile.getAbsolutePath))
  val fixedSvrCfg: ServerConfig = svrCfg.copy(
    configuration = Configuration(configWithFixedKeystorePath))

  private val sslEngineProv = new DefaultSSLEngineProvider(fixedSvrCfg, appProv)

  override def createSSLEngine(): SSLEngine = {
    sslEngineProv.createSSLEngine()
  }
}
```

And pass it as system property like:

`-Dplay.server.https.engineProvider=utils.CustomSSLEngineProvider`